# Overloading operator *

Tags: c++, eclipse, operator-overloading, ambiguous

I have a vector3 class which i need to implement different multiplication options ( so i overloaded the operator *) depending of the types that im multiplying.

The problem is that in the last one i get the error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ambiguating new declaration of 'Pang::vector3 Pang::operator*(const Pang::vector3&, const Pang::vector3&)'  vector3.h   /PangGame/src   line 130
```

C/C++ Problem

But i have only one `operator` overloaded that returns `vector` and muyltiplies two `vector`s.

Hope you can help ( just to clarify the class vector 3 has threee double numbers ) ex: `vector3(double x, double y, double z);` )

```
friend vector3 operator* (const double& number, const vector3& vector)
         {
     vector3 result;
     result.x = number*vector.x;
     result.y = number*vector.y;
     result.z = number*vector.z;
     return result;
         }

 friend vector3 operator* (const vector3& vector, const double& number)
             {
         vector3 result;
         result.x = number*vector.x;
         result.y = number*vector.y;
         result.z = number*vector.z;
         return result;
             }
 //Scalar product: If a = a1i + a2j + a3k and b = b1i + b2j + b3k then
 // a Â· b = a1*b1 + a2*b2 + a3*b3
 friend double operator* (const vector3& vector1, const vector3& vector2)
 {
         double result;
         result= (vector1.x)*(vector2.x)+(vector1.y)*(vector2.y) + (vector1.z)*(vector2.z);
         return result;
 }

 /* Product: Vector x Vector
  * Example: The cross product of a = (2,3,4) and b = (5,6,7)

 cx = aybz - azby = 3×7 - 4×6 = -3
 cy = azbx - axbz = 4×5 - 2×7 = 6
 cz = axby - aybx = 2×6 - 3×5 = -3
 Answer: a × b = (-3,6,-3)*/
 friend vector3 operator* (const vector3& vector,const vector3& vector2)
                 {
             vector3 result;
             result.x = (vector.y)*(vector2.z) - (vector.z)*(vector2.y);
             result.y = (vector.z)*(vector2.x) - (vector.x)*(vector2.z);
             result.z = (vector.x)*(vector2.y) - (vector.y)*(vector2.x);
             return result;
                 }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your two `operator*` functions have the same signature (arguments). Last time I tried, C++ didn't support overloading by return type alone.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to overload `operator*` based on the return type:

```
double operator* (const vector3& vector1, const vector3& vector2)
vector3 operator* (const vector3& vector1, const vector3& vector2)
```

This is not allowed because overload resolution takes into account the *function signature*, which [does not include the return type](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.signature):

> **3.19 signature [defns.signature]**
>
> ⟨function⟩ name, parameter-type-list, and enclosing namespace (if any)

---

One possible solution, if you do want your `operator*` to possibly yield either a `double` or another `vector3`, you can return a proxy type that is convertible to these types:

```
struct vector3_multiplication_proxy {
  vector3 lhs, rhs;
  operator double() { return 0; /* Your inner product calculation here */ }
  operator vector3() { return {}; /* Your cross product calculation here */ }
};

vector3_multiplication_proxy operator* (const vector3& lhs, const vector3& rhs) {
  return {lhs, rhs};
}
```

This does have lifetime pitfalls and may delay calculation depending on how you use it, so it may or may not be a good idea. In your particular case, it's probably a bad idea, because the inner and cross products are different things and should probably be denoted by different syntax.